# Yeoman angular-feature generator cdnify task not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've been looking for some automatic way to generate an angular app. I tried to use the angular generator on YEOMAN, but I didn't like the app structure provided.

I found out this other generator **angular-feature**(https://github.com/codigo-pl/generator-angular-feature) which seems to solve my problem. But so far I could not make it works. Every time when I try to generate the app(on feature structure) returns me an error:

command: **grunt build** (even if I try grunt server returns me the same)

> C:\Users\xxxxxx\WorkFolders\temp\testGenerator>grunt build Loading
>   "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>
> > > Error: Unable to parse C:\Users\xxxxxx\WorkFolders\temp\testGenerator .bowerrc:
> > >       Unexpected token v Warning: Task "cdnify" not found. Use --force to
> > >       continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

**UPDATE:**

Inside the file .bowerrc:

```
{
    "directory": "app\vendor/bower_components"
}
```

My folder after running generator:

```
testGenerator
--app
----src
------common
--node_modules
```

There's no **bower_components** folder in any place in my APP folder.

Has anyone already used this YEOMAN generator and had the same problem?
Is there another YEOMAN generator structured by feature like this one?

Comment: It looks like some issue with permissions. At work keeps not working(win 7). At home everything is working fine(MAC OSX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was sorted out and it was facing me all the time.

Problem

```
{
    "directory": "app\vendor/bower_components"
}
```

Solution

```
{
    "directory": "app/vendor/bower_components"
}
```

The generator is generating backslash instead slash. But the strange thing it seems be happening only on windows. Ubuntu and Mavericks I don't have this problem.

Comment: I've just realized the generator is putting backslash in different places over project. So far, I check out in the index.html and controller created by default.

Comment: I created a pull request in the original repository sorting out all the problems with slash/backslash on windows. And also fixing others problems with the grunt build process. Now it's working 100%.

https://github.com/serraventura/generator-angular-feature/tree/grunt-build-process-fix

Answer (score 5):

Try this command in your project to fix the issue.

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-google-cdn
```

I am really not sure why this isn't documented officially anywhere nor why the default Yeoman project generation script builds with errors. I had to execute searches to find out about this command.

Also, make sure you are using a *stable* version of Node/npm. One of my problems was that I was using the latest version of npm, which is 0.11.12. However, according to Node.js's website, that version is unstable. Instead, I had to use version 0.10.26, their latest stable version.

**Links:**

- https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/12
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yeoman-dev/3LFTPpqRInU

Comment: in my case the version is v0.10.25. I'll try .26

Comment: I've just remember. I'm unable to install a new version in my machine at work. I don't have permission.